# Facebook Like button information copied

Tags: facebook-like

When you click a Like button it seems to copy the page title, some meta words, one image, and the first quote it finds between `&quot;` marks to your Facebook page.  Does Facebook define somewhere exactly what is copied?

Also the copied information seems to be cached somewhere because if I change it on the website and unlike/relike the page, the old information still gets transferred again to Facebook.  Is there a way to clear this cache so new data is copied?

Thanks for your help,

Steve

Answer (score 1):

When you make changes to your page try running it through the Facebook URL debugger.

It's available at http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

This basically makes Facebook re-scrape your page and pull in any new/updated information

It will also show you all the information Facebook has gathered from the page

Answer (score 0):

Pages can define sections to be part of the open graph protocol using tags that Facebook retrieves in some way. Read the Getting Started section of this page:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

It explains how to use the open graph in your website.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Facebook caches page title,meta words, image for your URL when first time link or share button is hit or your URL is shared first time.The way to clear it is to change your URL.

There is another way: use Facebook tool called URL Linter. For this You can take a look at [here](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/390/)

Here are some processes you can follow.

[How to clear Facebbok Cache](http://umairj.com/146/how-to-clear-facebook-shares-cache/)